# Blackberry Banner class causes jvm 104 error

Tags: java, blackberry, banner-ads

Has anyone else had this issue before? I have a piece of code that basically does nothing. Its just a blank screen with a title, but when I add a place holder to a Banner object I get a 104 error.

At this point I am not even initializing the object, its just 
public Banner adBanner = null;

Solution:

There was actually 2 problems, the first was me being silly. I forgot to tell eclipse to export the external rim Ad library with the rest of the application. Once I fixed the build path it was mostly fine.

The second problem was apparently an issue with setting a Banner object to null (even when it wasnt getting executed. Despite including the library the line

```
Banner myBanner = null;
```

would cause a problem. As soon as I changed that to just be

```
Banner myBanner;
```

everything worked fine.

Comment: If I look at the simulator wrong, I sometimes get these errors.  Have you tried first cleaning the simulator and restarting?

Answer (score 1):

JVM 104 occurs in the BlackBerry smartphone simulator (shouldn't see it on a real device) when an uncaught exception is thrown.  This may or may not be happening within your application.  It does not necessarily mean there is a major problem, but it is alerting you that you have an exception that should be handled.